# NGRX/REDUX: update value in deep object by json path

Tags: javascript, redux, ngrx

I have an object like:

```
{
  categories: {
   Professional: {
    active: false,
    names: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "Golf",
        active: false
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "Ultimate Frisbee",
        active: false
      }
  ] 
}}
```

and i want update `categories.Professional.active` with `true`, into the reducer i have:

```
return {
  ...state,
  categories: {
    ...state.categories,
    Professional: {
      ...state.categories.Professional,
      active: true
    }
  }
}
```

now i want write a function for spreadfy an object and update a single property by json path. Eg.

```
return deepPatch(state, 'categories.Professional.active', true);
```

the goal for the function `deepPatch` is build at runtime this structure:

```
return Object.assign({}, obj, {
    categories: Object.assign({}, state.categories, {
      Professional: Object.assign({}, state.Professional, {
        active: true
      })
    })
});
```

i have tried but don't know how make a recursive spread:

```
function deepPatch(obj: any, path: string; value: any){
   const arrayPath: string[] = path.split('.');
   const currObj = null;
   for (let i = 0, e = arrayPath.length; i < e; i++) {
       const currPath = arrayPath[i];
       currObj = obj[currPath];
       currObj = Object.assign({}, currObj, ???);
   }
   return currObj;
}
```

Comment: If you have lodash as a dependency, you can use `_.set` https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get the first key and create a new object by calling the function again until no more keys are available.

```js
function deepPatch(object, path, value) {
    var [key, rest] = path.match(/^[^.]+|[^.].*$/g);

    return { ...object, [key]: rest
        ? deepPatch(object[key], rest, value)
        : value
    };
}

var state = { categories: { Professional: { active: false, names: [{ id: 1, name: "Golf", active: false }, { id: 2, name: "Ultimate Frisbee", active: false }] } } },
    result = deepPatch(state, 'categories.Professional.active', true);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const deepSet = function (object, path, value) {
    if (typeof path === 'string') {
        path = path.split('.');
    }
    if (path.length > 1) {
        const e = path.shift();
        deepSet(object[e] = Object.prototype.toString.call(object[e]) === '[object Object]' ? object[e] : {}, path, value);
    } else {
        object[path[0]] = value;
    }
};
```

I'm using this function. Works for me.